# Route Analyst acts odd at using custom impedance

Tags: arcgis-desktop, network, route

I need to do a route analysis with a custom made impedance, which is impedance based on the surface type. Here is the problem: while the route Analysis acts perfectly fine with the default cost "Length" (image 1), it will be messed up with my unknown custom cost "Surface_tpye" (image 2), which is based on the field suface_cost. Since I am using the same stops on both scenarios, there can't be breaks.

Any ideas to solve this problem?

[image: 1]

[image: 2]

[image: 3]

I also tried with the field length as impedance, same problems. Only works with default cost.

Comment: Could you please provide more details about how your network attributes are calculated and what their values are for the segments making up the shortest route?